# database rows polling service

Tags: php, mysql

I intend to develop lots of client voting systems capturing the following:

```
<?php

    $data = array(
          'vancancy' => 'PE',
    'pollingStation' => 'PS1001',
        'validVotes' => '400',
     'rejectedVotes' => '10',
        'validVotes' => '400',
       'base64Image' => 'VVVGGFTFTFHNBFVUWWSETD',
       'candidate 1' => '200',
       'candidate 2' => '100',
       'candidate 3' => '190',
       'base64Image' => 'VVVGGFTFTFHNBFVUWWSETD');

    $payload = json_encode($data);


    $url = 'http://localhost/APIS/RMS/jsonapi.php';
    $ch = curl_init($url);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $payload);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content- 
  Type:application/json'));

    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    echo $response;
    curl_close($ch);
    ?>
```

At the central server where the posting is done; i have STAGING database table that receives the json data and keeps it as TEXT.

I  want a SERVICE that should regularly poll the STAGING table and split  the json TEXT into separate fields to populate in another resulting table (storing candidate 1, 2, 3 and the amount of votes. After each row is read, then a flag in staging table must be set so I read it again. At the results table I must calculate how many votes each candidate has in another total votes.

*@@@@@@@@@@@ THis is the API code receiving results from clients@@@@@@@@*

```
<?php
header("Content-Type:application/json");
require 'checkSQLInsertion.php';

// read the incoming POST body (the JSON)
$input = file_get_contents('php://input');

if($input) 
{
$SQLInsertStatus=get_insertStatus($input);

if($SQLInsertStatus)
{
    response(200,1);//No SQL Insertion
}
else
{
    response(200,0); //Successful SQL Insetion
}

}
else
{
response(400,"If you can see this, then Web Service is Working, try 
again!! ");
}

function response($status,$ack)
{
header("HTTP/1.1 ".$status);

$response['status']=$status;
$response['status_message']=$ack;

$json_response = json_encode($response);
echo $json_response;
}
```

Comment: Is there a question or did you just want to show your code?

Comment: I wanted to show the code but wondering if the output of the API should be echo $json_response; or return  $json_response;

Comment: in the function `return $json_response;`, when you call the function `echo response(200,0);`